# Laravel : Call to undefined method Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

On query get the error with undefine method. Simply i want to get data from two tables query look linke

```
  public static function userDetail($id){


    $result = User::whereHas('user_details', function ($query) {
        $query->where('user_details.user_id',$id);
    })->first();


    return $result ;
}
```

Relationship

On Model `User` define relationship

```
public function userDetails()
{
   return $this->hasOne(UserDetails::class);
}
```

and in `userDetails` model

```
public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
```

Comment: 'user_details' should be `userDetails` in `whereHas`

Comment: You will also need to add `use($id)` here: `function ($query) use ($id)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just change

```
public static function userDetail($id){


$result = User::whereHas('user_details', function ($query) use($id) {
    $query->where('user_id',$id);
})->first();


return $result ;
```

}

Comment: ` "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'userDetails.user_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `users` where exists (select * from `user_details` where `users`.`id` = `user_details`.`user_id` and `userDetails`.`user_id` = 2) limit 1)",`

Comment: This means `user_id` column in your `userDetails` table didn't exist.

Comment: if it works please accept the answer and upvote. @Javed

Answer (score 1):

If you dont need to use **static**, you can use this $result value on userDetails

```
public function userDetail($id){

        $result = userDetails::where('user_id', '=', $id)->first();

        return $result ;
}
```

Then the result can get access to the user from the vale by using $value->user->{user property}